# How do I limit the number of ticket to be sold in events

Tags: civievent, registration

We have a event created, where the maximum participants are set to 120. But since a single participant can buy a multiple ticket, I am not able to find a way to limit ticket to be sold to 120.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use price sets to track purchased tickets instead of just registrants.

See this reference (down the page to 'complex event fees with price sets'

http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/events/creating-an-event/

Comment: In particular, search this page for the words "Participant Count".

Comment: We already had a event running with the existing price-set but looks like it's not configurable after the price-set is already in use. This should be taken care before you create price-sets.

Answer (score 0):

I had written a comment to set the max participants in the Event settings ,  but you have already done that. So,  never mind.